# How to update numba for a particular environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, numba

I have Anacondas installed on my windows machine.

I have installed the Python 3.3 environment.

I would like to update my numba to 0.11 on this environment (it is currently 0.9).

However, when I run "conda update numba" it appears to update numba for Python 2.7.

I cannot find any documentation to get it to update numba in my 3.3 environment.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you created the environment using `-n`, then you can use that same flag to other commands to get to that environment, like

```
conda update -n py33 numba
```

Alternatively, if the environment is activated, you can just `conda update` it

```
source activate py33
conda update numba
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if the environment is activated".  I cannot run source from either the command line or ipython.

Comment: That command only works on Linux and OS X. On Windows, it's just `activate py33`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can update it on my machine using this:

```
conda update -p /anaconda/envs/py33/ numba
```